# UIScrollView in custom table cell at cellForRowAtIndex path not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a `UIScrollView` in each cell of `UITableView'. I wrote my code based on Apple's custom Scrollview project: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Each table cell's `UIScrollView` scrolls through a set of labels, which are initialized in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Each label's text is set after initialization to equal a string from an array.

Everything works correctly until I scroll down to the 4th table cell. The `UIScrollView` in this cell has the same exact labels as the first cell. The same first 3 set of labels or the first 3 scrollViews keep repeating after the first 3 cells. The strange part is, when I log the `label.text` after it is set, the output shows the correct `label.text` of what should be displaying in the respective cell.

```
- (void)layoutScrollLabels: (float)arrayCount
{
UIView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [cell.popularLinkScrollView subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && view.tag >= 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

[cell.popularLinkScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((arrayCount * kScrollObjWidth),     [cell.popularLinkScrollView bounds].size.height)];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Custom Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [parseDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *popularLinkTitleArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"popularLinkTitleArray"];

cell.popularLinkScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

kScrollObjHeight = cell.popularLinkScrollView.frame.size.height;
kScrollObjWidth = cell.popularLinkScrollView.frame.size.width;

NSUInteger i;
for (i = 0; i < popularLinkTitleArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [popularLinkTitleArray objectAtIndex: i]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 5;
    NSLog(@"%@", label.text);

    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = label.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    label.frame = rect;
    label.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
    [cell.popularLinkScrollView addSubview:label];
}

[self layoutScrollLabels:popularLinkTitleArray.count];
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: try typecasting cell = (Customcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];what is popularlinktitlearray

Comment: What do you mean by typecasting? popularLinkTitleArray includes the strings that are appended to the labels. I don't have it defined in the above code, but it is working correctly when I `NSLog` the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add label as a subview to popularLinkScrollView in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If the count of labels is required to be dynamic, try this code before your for loop in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
for (UIView* subView in cell.popularLinkScrollView.subviews)
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Ok, that works. I just needed to change the for statement to: `for (UIView* subView in cell.popularLinkScrollView.subviews)`. Thank you. By the way, why do you suggest not adding the label in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Where should I be adding it?

Comment: If the count of such labels is known and always fixed, you should put it in the implementation of CustomCell itself. If on the other hand it is not fixed. you can try two approaches 1) If you know the maximum count of labels and labels are in a particular order, have maximum labels added in CustomCell implementation and hide/unhide labels in cellForRowAtIndexPath. 2) The other approach is as suggested above.

Comment: It is fixed, but I don't quite understand how to put it in my CustomCell implementation. Do I create a method in the CustomCell .m and call the method in ViewController `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: You can have a xib file for your CustomCell. If you are not aware of how to create custom cells through xib file, I suggest you to browse Apple example codebase for application named "AdvancedTableViewCells" that explains different aspects of working with custom cells.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mithlesh. I took a look at AdvancedTableCells.  I understand that I can put my label creation code in a method in my implementation. What I don't understand, is how and when to call this method. Can I use viewDidLoad in CustomCell.m? Do I call a CustomCell method in CellForRowAtIndexPath? If so, how?

Comment: I've accomplished this in the implementation, but I have poor scrolling performance. I have opened a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669139/uitableview-scrolling-slow-memory-leak-issue