# UITableView scrolling slow, memory leak issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and a `UITableCell` subclass. Each table cell has two `scrollviews` that each rotate a dynamic amount of labels, which are created in my table cell implementation. I have poor scrolling performance and I believe it is from memory leaks. I'm referencing this `stackoverflow correct answer to fix my problem`: [cellForRowAtIndexPath memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859735/cellforrowatindexpath-memory-management).

I can't figure out how to tweak my code so I don't have to allocate memory every time I create labels.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Custom Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


NSDictionary *dictionary = [parseDataArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

NSArray *popularLinkTitleArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"popularLinkTitleArray"];
NSString *soundCloudLink = [dictionary objectForKey:@"soundCloudLink"];
NSArray *soundCloudTrackTitleArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"soundCloudTrackTitleArray"];


cell.artistNameLabel.text = artistName;

[cell createPopularLinkLabels: popularLinkTitleArray];

return cell;
}
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
- (void)layoutScrollLabelsForPopularLinkScrollView: (float)arrayCount
{
UIView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [popularLinkScrollView subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && view.tag >= 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

[popularLinkScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((arrayCount * kScrollObjWidth),    [popularLinkScrollView bounds].size.height)];

}

-(void) createPopularLinkLabels:(NSArray *) popularLinkTitleArray
{

popularLinkScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

kScrollObjHeight = popularLinkScrollView.frame.size.height;
kScrollObjWidth = popularLinkScrollView.frame.size.width;

for (UIView* subView in popularLinkScrollView.subviews)
    [subView removeFromSuperview];

NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 0; i < popularLinkTitleArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [popularLinkTitleArray objectAtIndex: i]];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.numberOfLines = 5;
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:18]];

        // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
        CGRect rect = label.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        label.frame = rect;
        label.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
        [popularLinkScrollView addSubview:label];
    }

[self layoutScrollLabelsForPopularLinkScrollView:popularLinkTitleArray.count];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you could do is try to reuse UILabels in createPopularLinkLabels. Right now, you are just removing them before adding more.

But if the number of popular links is not the same in all the cells, then you will have to remove the remaining ones or hide them and there will be no way to avoid memory allocations.

A better solution would be to insert a custom UIView inside your scroll view and draw all the texts manually instead of creating tons of subviews.

Hope this helps,
Thomas

Comment: Can you give more detail on how to insert a UIView and draw texts? I'm new to iOS. Thanks!

Comment: Drawing view texts for each cell's scrollview would be more efficient than using UILabels?

Comment: Hey - Sorry, I missed your reply... Look at: "Subclassing UITableViewCell" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: However, it used to be a lot faster to draw cell content by hand but after re-reading the doc I am not sure this is still true. You might want to start by setting all your UILabel to opaque=YES first and see if that improves performance. The idea is to make it easier for the cell to redraw itself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ARC?  If not, you should autorelease to

```
cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]
```

Cell objects are reused and you do not need to re-add subviews each time you change the contents.  Just change the data and update the label frames if needed.

If you have distinctly different cells, consider using separate custom cell classes.  You will need to use a separate value for the reuseIdentifier.

Also consider not creating a custom cell but just adding elements to the standard UITableViewCell.  [Read this about styling a cell](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

Comment: i think you don't need if(cell == nil). because cell will release automatically on scroll ends. so each time cell will create.